# Specifying different images as left and right borders css

Tags: css-sprites, css

I have to mix 2 images (from different sprites) and generate a single button out of them.
I tried using the css properties 'border-left-image' and 'border-right-image' in chrome. But it does not work. Tried pre-pending the

Answer (score 0, accepted):

id have a look here

http://css-tricks.com/6883-understanding-border-image/

this should explain what you need to do and what is doable!

UPDATE

looks like you might be able to accomplish this using multiple background images which is CSS3 based take a look at the link for more information!

http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I did actually go through that link. I found no way in which I could accommodate 2 images as border images.

Comment: ok i dont use alot of the new css properties, there any way you can add in another element to handle it?

Comment: dont think so...whatever the case, I have to achieve it via css

Comment: try multiple background images this is available in css3 look here http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/ will update answer to show it!

Comment: I tried setting 2 images in background-image property and they did come out fine. My problem came when I wanted to actually move the first image a little left. I tried to do that as I wanted to overlap another existing button on top of which I am adding this new button.

Comment: might be worth trying to use negative margins ect to get the desired effect!

Comment: ok, will give that a try...is there any way in which I can make a button totally transparent? Even the borders. Wish I could kind of make the button invisible. :)

Comment: yep background-color:transparent; this should remove the background then border-color:transparent; color:transparent; think you get the idea :P

Comment: used a combination of left and right background images with background-position properties